# Having a problem with the kivy attribute error. How to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'property'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to use a mainwindow as a screenmanager with, login screen and user screen. Running the code gives the above mentioned error. But individual apps work fine without the mainwindow.

main.py:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

from user.user import UserWindow
from signin.signin import LoginScreen

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    user_widget = UserWindow()
    signin_widget = LoginScreen()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.id.scrn_si.add_widget(self.signin_widget)
        self.id.scrn_usr.add_widget(self.signin_widget)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Gray"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()

if __name__=='__main__':
MainApp().run()
```

With its respective kv file below

main.kv:

```
<MainWindow>
    id: main_win

    ScreenManager:
        id: scrn_mngr_main

        Screen:
            id: scrn_si
            name: 'scrn_si'

        Screen:
            id: scrn_usr
            name: 'scrn_usr'
```

Next i have the `signin.py` which is the sign-in screen.

signin/signin.py:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_file('signin/sign.kv')

class LoginScreen(BoxLayout):

    def validate_user(self):
        user = self.ids.email_field
        pwd = self.ids.pwd_field
        info = self.ids.info

        uname = user.text
        passw = pwd.text

        if uname == '' or passw =='':
            info.text = '[color=#FF0000]username and/ or password required[/color]'
        else:
            if uname == 'admin' and passw == 'admin':
                info.text = '[color=#00FF00]Logged In Succesfully!![/color]'
            else:
                info.text = '[color=#FF0000]Invalid Username and/ or Password[/color]'

class SignApp(MDApp):
    title = "LOGIN SCREEN"

    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()



    def show_password(self, field, button):
        """
        Called when you press the right button in the password field
        for the screen TextFields.

        instance_field: kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput;
        instance_button: kivymd.button.MDIconButton;

        """

        # Show or hide text of password, set focus field
        # and set icon of right button.
        field.password = not field.password
        field.focus = True
        button.icon = 'eye' if button.icon == 'eye-off' else 'eye-off'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sa = SignApp()
    sa.run()
```

Its respective .kv file `sign.kv`

signin/sign.kv:

```
<LoginScreen>:
    id: "login"
    orientation:"vertical"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.188235294,0.188235294,0.188235294
        Rectangle:
            #source: "mountain2.png"
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: .8, .5
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        height: self.minimum_height
        spacing: dp(15)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        Label:
            id: info
            text: ''
            markup: True


        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: email_field
            icon_left: "email"
            icon_right: "account-box"
            icon_right_disabled: True
            size_hint: 1, None
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            hint_text: "Email"
            foreground_color: 0, 0, 0, 0.8
            focus: True
            on_text_validate: pwd_field.focus = True

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: pwd_field
            icon_type: "all"
            icon_left: "key-variant"
            icon_right: "eye-off"
            icon_right_disabled: False
            #icon_callback: app.show_password
            password: True
            size_hint: 1, None
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            hint_text: "Password"
            foreground_color: 0, 0, 0, 0.8
            on_text_validate: root.validate_user()

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Login"
            size_hint: .9, None
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            md_bg_color: 1, 0.64705058823, 0, 1
            on_release: root.validate_user()

        MDTextButton:
            text: "Forgot your password?"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .75}
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1
```

And finally the user screen `user.py`

user/user.py:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.factory import Factory

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_file('user/user.kv')

class MyTab(BoxLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass


class MyTab2(BoxLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass


class MyTab3(BoxLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass


class UserWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class UserApp(MDApp):

    title = 'DEMO'
    dropdown = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Gray"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_start(self):
        # Create the dropdown menu
        self.dropdown = MDDropdownMenu(width_mult=2)

        # Add items to the menu
        for i in range(6):
            self.dropdown.items.append(
                {"viewclass": "MDMenuItem",
                 "text": "Option " + str(i),
                 "callback": self.option_callback}
            )

    def option_callback(self, text_of_the_option):
        print(text_of_the_option)

    def build(self):
        screen = Factory.UserWindow()

        tab = MyTab(text='Home Tab')
        screen.ids.android_tabs.add_widget(tab)

        tab = MyTab2(text='Approved Tickets')
        screen.ids.android_tabs.add_widget(tab)

        tab = MyTab3(text='History')
        screen.ids.android_tabs.add_widget(tab)
        return screen


if __name__ == '__main__':
    oa = UserApp()
    oa.run()
```

Next is `user.kv` file

user/user.kv:

```
<UserWindow>
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: app.title
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        background_palette: 'Primary'
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: app.dropdown.open(x)]]

    MDTabs:
        id: android_tabs


<MyTab>
    FloatLayout:

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Open day picker"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
            on_release:
                app.dropdown.open(self)

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Open destination picker"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .8}

<MyTab2>

    FloatLayout:


<MyTab3>
    FloatLayout:
```

This is the error that i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pakomoaro/Desktop/INTERFACE/DEMO/main.py", line 8, in <module>
     class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
   File "/home/pakomoaro/Desktop/INTERFACE/DEMO/main.py", line 9, in MainWindow
     user_widget = UserWindow()
   File "/home/pakomoaro/Desktop/INTERFACE/DEMO/user/user.py", line 26, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/boxlayout.py", line 145, in __init__
     super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 361, in __init__
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 469, in apply_class_lang_rules
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 538, in apply
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 654, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivymd/uix/toolbar.py", line 191, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivymd/theming.py", line 369, in __init__
     App.get_running_app().property("theme_cls", True),
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'property'
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc dont  know how to add an example can you help me with that. I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: @eyllanesc just checked it out. Thank you. Edited the question.

Comment: You should not delete the error message, please add it back.

Comment: @eyllanesc added the error message.